# How to show the xml content from the ajax's method result?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I invoke a WebService method via jQuery

.js code

```
  $.ajax({
     url: '/ms.asmx/se2',
     data: {},
     success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
          },
         dataType: 'text'
    });
```

.asmx method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string se2()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
```

the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">OK</string>
```

How to show only that XML content - `OK` - instead the XML code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a function to parse XML: `$.parseXML` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). In addition, if you pass 'xml' to `dataType`, jQuery will automatically parse it as xml.

So:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ms.asmx/se2',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        alert( $(result).find('string').text() );
    }
    dataType: 'xml'
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that code doesn't work (the alert doesn't show). I use jquery 1.6.2

Comment: Try `alert( $(result).find('string').text() )`

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this change.